# Robocopy directory and its contents

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I feel like this should be straightforward, but I've been struggling with this for long enough that it's making me pull my hair out.  I'm writing a couple batch files to do automated file syncing and some cleanup between a few different drives.  When copying a directory I use the following command.

```
robocopy %datestr% %2 /E
```

What this line of code does is take the contents of the path specified by %datestr% and copies it to the path specified by %2.  I need it to copy the directory itself (and its contents, of course) to the path specified by %2.  I looked at the Robocopy docs and I can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

EDIT:  I fixed the problem I was having, but it feels more like a hack than a fix.  Appending the source folder to the destination path 'copies' it, as such:

```
robocopy %datestr% "%2/%datestr%" /E
```

I don't love the fact that this isn't truly 'copying' it, but just making a new directory with the same name.  For what I'm using this it will work fine, but I still feel as if there must be a better way to do so.

Comment: If you found a solution yourself, please post it as an answer and revert the edit of the question!

Comment: Actually you have found the true solution! `robocopy` copies the attributes of the source directory to the destination directory. When the destination directory already exists, you need to add the `/DCOPY:DAT` option to also apply the original time stamp from the source; when the destination does not exist, the time stamp is applied even without that option. NTFS security settings are not regarded, unfortunately. Anyway, if you do not care about any attributes, copying the directory is equivalent to creating it...

Comment: **note:** Windows uses a back, not forward, slash in it's file paths.

Comment: **Note note**: several commands in Windows will accept either, but prefer backslashes